# python tkinter - Deleting all TreeView Children

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, ttk, ttkwidgets

I will like to create a clear button that will delete all the records in the treeview while at the same time, I am trying to improve my OOP via Tkinter at the same. (So if there is other non-best practice in the code; could you please advise as well).

From what I found out through googling, I could possibl use a get_children method on treeview, retrieve them and then subsequently deleting them one bye one.

```
def delButton(self):
    x = main.tree.get_children()
    for item in x:
        main.tree.delete(item)
```

However, i keep getting attribute error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_children'. Is it the way I reference in in my classes?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk,messagebox


gray = '#808080'
green = '#7FFF00'
black = '#000000'
filter_font = ('Arial',12,'bold')
search_font = ('Arial',10)

class News:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.geometry("1000x500")
        self.window.resizable(0,0)


        self.quit_button = self.create_quit_button()
        self.clear_button = self.create_clear_button()

        self.tree_view = self.create_tree_view()




    def create_tree_view(self):
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.window,columns=(1,2,3,4) , show= 'headings',height='12')
        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=6, columnspan=9, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.tree.column(1,width=70)
        self.tree.column(2,width=70)

        self.tree.heading(1,text ='Hello',anchor='w')
        self.tree.heading(2,text ='World',anchor='w')

        self.tree.insert(parent='',index='end',iid=0,values = ['John','John@gmail.com'])
        self.tree.insert(parent='',index='end',iid=1,values = ['John','John@gmail.com'])



        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=6, columnspan=9, padx=10, pady=10)


    def create_clear_button(self):
        self.clear_button = tk.Button(self.window,text='Clear',fg=green,bg = black,command = lambda : self.clear())
        self.clear_button.grid(row=0,column=20)

    def create_quit_button(self):
        quit_button = tk.Button(self.window,text='Quit',fg=green,bg = black,command =lambda: self.quit())
        quit_button.grid(row =4,column = 10)


    def quit(self):
        self.window.quit()

    def run(self):
        self.window.mainloop()


    def clear(self):
        for item in self.tree_view.get_children():
            self.tree.delete(item)
        return (self.tree)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    news = News()
    news.run()
```

Comment: Is `delButton()` a method inside `News` class? What is `main` in that function? Better provide a [mre].

Comment: As, @acw1668 pointed out it would be helpful to find a solution to the problem given a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Specifically, because it is unclear which class bears the method `delButton`.

Comment: delButton () shall be clear(self). I have edited the code. thank you and sorry for the trouble

Comment: Note that `self.tree_view` is used in the `for item in ...` line, but `self.tree` is used inside the for loop. `self.tree_view` is `None` as it is the result of `create_tree_view()` which does not return anything.  Use `self.tree` inside `clear()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that inside `clear()`, you have used `self.tree_view` in the line `for item in ...`, while `self.tree` is used inside the for loop block:

```py
def clear(self):
    for item in self.tree_view.get_children(): # used self.tree_view
        self.tree.delete(item)                 # used self.tree
    return (self.tree)
```

`self.tree_view` is `None` because it is the result of `create_tree_view()` which does not return anything:

```py
self.tree_view = self.create_tree_view()
```

Actually you don't need `self.tree_view`, use `self.tree` in `clear()`:

```py
def clear(self):
    for item in self.tree.get_children(): # used self.tree instead
        self.tree.delete(item)
    #return (self.tree) # return here is useless as clear() is triggered by a button
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! I realize what i did wrongly now.

For people new to OOP programming, as @acw1668 point up, self.tree_view is None because it is the result of create_tree_view() which does not return anything.

I should have [return self.tree] in my function when creating the self.tree_view. Once that is done, i could have then : 

    def clear(self):
        for item in self.tree_view.get_children():
            self.tree_view.delete(item)
        return (self.tree_view)